# Source for choosing your meal guests wisely

Tags: sources-mekorot, meal-seudah

During a recorded shiur I heard recently, the Rav quoted a Chazal saying, "The ותיקי ירושלים wouldn't eat a meal with others unless they knew the other guests so that they wouldn't join in a meal with an individual who wasn't fit to eat with - אינו הגון." After searching all over, I still can't find this statement - where is the source of this Chazal, or anything similar to it?

Comment: Interesting yet relevant point: The [Mishnah Berurah](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.170.20?lang=he&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.170.42&lang2=he&p3=Biur_Halacha.170.20.1&lang3=he) brings from the *Achronim* that this rule **applies even to a *seudas mitzvah***, and he admits that he doesn't know the source for that novelty. However, ostensibly the source is an explicit [Tosafos in Pesachim](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Pesachim.113b.14?vhe=Vilna_Edition&lang=bi).

Comment: Bm 23 kyadua b'tosfos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source is a *beraita* quoted in [Sanhedrin 23a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.23a.16?lang=bi):

> תניא נמי הכי כך היו נקיי הדעת שבירושלים עושין לא היו חותמין על השטר אלא א"כ יודעין מי חותם עמהן ולא היו יושבין בדין אלא א"כ יודעין מי יושב עמהן **ולא היו נכנסין בסעודה אלא אם כן יודעין מי מיסב עמהן**:‏
>
> That is also taught: This is what the scrupulous people of Jerusalem would do: They would not sign a document unless they knew who was signing with them, and they would not sit in judgment unless they knew who was sitting with them, **and they would not join a meal unless they knew who was reclining with them**.

Answer (score 3):

JoelK gave the source specifically mentioning the נקיי הדעת. But as the OP asked for sources, it's worth noting the gemara in [brachos 43b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.43b.11-17?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) which adds a reason to avoid eating with "unfit people":

תָּנוּ רַבָּנַן: שִׁשָּׁה דְּבָרִים גְּנַאי לוֹ לְתַלְמִיד חָכָם...וְאַל יָסֵב בַּחֲבוּרָה שֶׁל עַמֵּי הָאָרֶץ: מַאי טַעְמָא? — דִּילְמָא אָתֵי לְאִמְּשׁוֹכֵי בָּתְרַיְיהוּ

"Six things are a "genai" (disgrace, degradation) for a talmid chacham... He shouldn't have a meal with ignoramuses. What's the reason? Lest he be drawn after them."

This halacha is codified in the Rambam in [Hilchos Deos 5:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Human_Dispositions.5.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)